# Paste Text Field and Button over an ImageView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

This is the login activity I want to achieve in my app (Image2).  But I do not know how to do so it because I cannot paste the **editText**, **password** and **button** over the white part of the image (the whole image has black border). The app has white background and I want to make the look of the image as curve and to place the other fields under it. For now it looks as image1.

[image]

and look this

[image]

I also want my image to be aligned to the bottom and its width to be match_parent and the height to be adjusted so that the ratio of the original image is saved on different devices. Here is my XML code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5"
    tools:context="com.example.android.start.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_weight="2"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/image2"

    />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you should use FrameLayout

Comment: Use widgets under RelativeLayout and set your image as background of it, your problem will be solved.

Comment: use FrameLayout, and you provide the second image as second FrameLayout background. Then add the edit text with specific padding from top

Comment: Thank you @Navas pk, using FrameLayout and setting the image as a background worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I used to achieve the look from Image2:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5"
    tools:context="com.example.android.start.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:weightSum="2">
         <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

             <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/name"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:background="#C8E6C9"
                 android:ems="10"
                 android:hint="Username"
                 android:inputType="textPersonName"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="117dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

             <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:text="Sign In"
                 android:background="#8BC34A"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="11dp" />

             <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/password"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                 android:background="#C8E6C9"
                 android:ems="10"
                 android:hint="Password"
                 android:inputType="textPassword"
                 android:layout_above="@+id/button"
                 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
                 android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="19dp" />
             />

         </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/banner"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="5"
tools:context="com.example.android.start.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/image2">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you but it did not work. I managed to solve my problem using FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` it will hopefully solve your problem.